# How to dynamically find the main content DIV of an HTML document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I started to build a jQuery plugin which need to dynamically find the main content DIV ID/CLASS in HTML document, so I could manipulate it whatever I want.

f.e:

```
<div id="wrapper">

   <div id="main">I need to find this DIV.</div>

   <div id="sidebar"></div>

</div>
```

Keep in mind that the id="main" can get totally different values such as "main-wrapper" or "mainDiv" or whatever web developers using... 
What is the logic that I need for this?

Comment: Do you need to do this for arbitrary documents, because there's no way to tell this just from a small snippet. Not all sites will call it "main" or whatever.

Comment: You have to provide way more information. What constitutes the "main content div" in your case?

Comment: How do you define "main".  And for what purpose.  The only tag you have on your question is `html`.  I assume you intend to use `javascript`?

Comment: Yeah, I know it's exactly what I said.
I don't expect you to write me the full JS code, just to give me an idea of how to do it? :)

Comment: How do you define "main content DIV"  pages are made up by lots of parts, not everyone structures their pages the same way.  Either I'm not understanding or what your asking is not possible.

Comment: It's for a jQuery plugin i'm writing.
Anyone can add it to their websites. Therefor I need to find the main content DIV by myself without the site owner to provide it.

Comment: @fastrd, if you want good answers you need to take the time to ask a good question. You haven't provided enough details for anyone to help you. If you can't be bothered to give us the information we need, we wont be bothered to give you the assistance you want.

Comment: Why wouldn't the user of your plugin just tell you what `<div>` they wanted the plugin to operate on? For example: `$('#main').yourPluginMethod();`

Comment: @zzzzBov I edited my question. Is that's good enough?

Comment: @FishBasketGordo Because I want it to be dynamically.

Comment: @fastrd What if the main content is in a `<section>` tag?  What if the author of the page preferred to use Turkish names for elements?  Why not, therefore, instruct your users to give the class "main-content" to whatever element should be affected by the plugin?

Comment: @fastrd: You need to provide an example of how you think this plugin should work then. It's not at all clear. Most jQuery plugins work the way that I show in my previous comment.

Comment: @Pointy You're right. It's could happen. So I need to get this element and pass it to my plugin.
I saw a great example for something like this in "Clearly" (A chrome extension):
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/iooicodkiihhpojmmeghjclgihfjdjhj

How did they do it??

Comment: @fastrd that tool does not always work, and it requires user customization for some (probably many) pages. The problem is that there are millions of ways a page author might structure a page. Perhaps a tool like that "knows" what several common CMS systems do, and how Wordpress pages look, and things like that, but it's still going to be hit-or-miss.

Answer (score 2):

As I said in a comment, the way to do this is to instruct the users of your plugin to add a class to the element they want affected:

```
<section id='My-Favorite-Section' class='fastrd-plugin-main'>
  ...
</section>
```

Then your plugin can use a "ready" handler to look for ".fastrd-plugin-main" (or whatever you want to use).

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.fastrdPlugin = function() {
    // ...
  };

  $(function() {
    $('.fastrd-plugin-main').fastrdPlugin();
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Any attempt to "find" the right element of any arbitrary page is doomed to a low success rate, at best.

Comment: I know how a jQuery plugin usually works. The plugin I am developing is this: 
http://yourhere.gandtblog.com

And currently it works just like you suggest, but I'm looking for other solution.